# Placing pagenumber in a Tikz shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, numbering, page-numbering, xepersian

Im writing a book in Persian (whose direction is right to left) and i want the page numbers appear like the code below:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    %\usepackage{xepersian} % If this enables problem occurs
    %\settextfont{Adobe Arabic} % Or \settextfont{Yas}
    \fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%   
      \fancyhf{}%
      \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)},anchor=center] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill = black!30,
          draw = black!20,
          anchor=west,
          ]
          (pageno)
          {\phantom\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill = black!30,
          draw = black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=-\oddsidemargin-1in]pageno.north west)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south east);
        \node[
        anchor=east,
        font=\color{white}
        ]
          at (pageno.east)
          {\thepage};  
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
      \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)},anchor=east] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          anchor=east,
          ]
          (pageno)
          {\phantom{\thepage}};
        \draw[
          fill = black!30,
          draw = black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=\paperwidth-\textwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in]pageno.north west)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south west);
        \node[
        anchor=west,
        font=\color{white}
        ]
          at (pageno.west)
          {\thepage};  
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    }%
    %% without the following the chapter pages won't have fancy page style
    %\makeatletter
    %\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
    %\makeatother
    %

    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{myfancy}
    \chapter{تست ۱}
     \lipsum[1-5]
     \section{تست ۲}
        \lipsum[1-5]

    \end{document}
```

the code compiles perfect without `xepersian` package, but after using this package, the even page numbers misfit.
Does any body have idea about this?

**Edit**:
what I need:
[image: desirable figure]
the code in the second answer produces this:
[image: edited answer]

Comment: Hello! Due to the change from left-to-right to right-to-left, the way how TikZ interpretes east and west is different. So, you need to reconfigure the anchors in the `tikzpicture` parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the change from left-to-right to right-to-left, the way how Tik*Z* interpretes east and west is different. So, you need to reconfigure the anchors in the tikzpicture parts.

I simplified your code a bit and switched `east` and `west` accordingly where appropriate, so that the code now should be suited for right-to-left typesetting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{xepersian} 
    \settextfont{Amiri} % I didn't have the other fonts

    \fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%   
      \fancyhf{}%
      \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=east,
        ]
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=\oddsidemargin+1in]pageno.north east)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
      \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=west,
        ]
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=-\oddsidemargin-1in]pageno.north west)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myfancy}

    \chapter{تست ۱}
        \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{تست ۲}
        \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Of course, this means that if you comment the `xepersian` package again, this solution will again not work.

[image]

---

**Edit**

Even and odd pages changed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{xepersian} % If this enables problem occurs
    \settextfont{Amiri} % Or \settextfont{Yas}

    \fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%   
      \fancyhf{}%
      \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=west,
        ]
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=-\paperwidth+\textwidth-\oddsidemargin]pageno.north west)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
      \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=east,
        ]
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=\paperwidth-\textwidth+\oddsidemargin]pageno.north east)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myfancy}

    \chapter{تست ۱}
        \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{تست ۲}
        \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

---

**Second Edit**

Somehow, different versions of one of the used packages behave differently as to how to interprete east and west. The above answer currently works on Overleaf which I used for testing.

The following should work with the most current packages (as of 5 Feb 2019):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{xepersian} % If this enables problem occurs
    \settextfont{Amiri} % Or \settextfont{Yas}

    \fancypagestyle{myfancy}{%   
      \fancyhf{}%
      \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=west
        ] at (-0.5\textwidth,0)        
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=east
        ]
          ([xshift=-\paperwidth+\textwidth-\oddsidemargin]pageno.north west)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
      \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline={(0,0)}] 
        \node[
          rectangle,
          outer sep=0pt,
          text=white,
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
          anchor=east
        ] at (\textwidth,0)
          (pageno)
          {\thepage};
        \draw[
          fill=black!30,
          draw=black!20,
        ]
          ([xshift=\paperwidth-\textwidth+\oddsidemargin]pageno.north east)
            rectangle  
          (pageno.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}%  
        }%
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myfancy}

    \chapter{تست ۱}
        \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{تست ۲}
        \lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help, this looks what I needed, but the odd and even positionings have been replaced with each other, e.g. `ER ` should show up right side and `OL` should appear left side. and as soon as I get home I will accept as the answe. As the last question, does this kind of page numbering interfere with the footnotes or they can be used together?

Comment: i couldn't produce the correct results

Comment: Footnotes should not interfere with this layout. Remember to switch back to a font that you have installed. I changed the font to Amiri. Could you provide more information on the result you get and how it is wrong?

Comment: the post have been updated:take a look

Comment: Well, I re-tested the code of my second answer and it does not generate the result you post above. Maybe, in your document, you also use some other packages that interfere somehow. Do you get the same wrong results when you try only to compile the code that I provided?

Comment: hmm!!? there's sth wrong, because the picture is only of your code , i just have added some text to it, 
here is the pdf i've created with your code
https://ufile.io/yweta

Comment: OK, I just tested it with another setup. The second answer works on Overleaf, but maybe they don’t have the most recent versions of all packages installed on their servers. The third answer should work with the most recent setup.